# angularjs ng-value and value

Tags: php, html

```
<select name="test1" ng-model="test11" ng-init="test11=0">
     <option value="MULTIMETER" ng-value="60"></option>
</select>
```

When I get the value from PHP: `$test = $_POST['test1'];`, it gives the value 60 (ng-value=0). I want to get the value `'MULTIMETER'`. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Take out the ng-value.

Answer (score 0):

case 1 : in test11 model value is 60 when select MULTIMETER

```
<select name="test1" ng-model="test11" ng-init="test11=0">
             <option ng-value="60">MULTIMETER</option>
           </select>
```

case 2 : in test11 model value is MULTIMETER when select 60

```
<select name="test1" ng-model="test11" ng-init="test11=0">
             <option ng-value="MULTIMETER">60</option>
           </select>
```

case 3 : in test11 model value is MULTIMETER when select 60 default selected

```
<select name="test1" ng-model="test11" ng-init="test11=0">
             <option ng-selected="true" ng-value="MULTIMETER">60</option>
           </select>
```

case 4 : Try it

```
<select name="test1" ng-model="test11">
             <option ng-selected="true" ng-value="MULTIMETER">MULTIMETER</option>
           </select>
```

Comment: ` <select name="test1" ng-model="test11" ng-init="test11=0">
             <option value="MULTIMETER" ng-value="60">MULTI</option>
           </select>`

Comment: what you want ? please explain.

Comment: have you got your answer ?

Comment: ` <select name="test1" ng-model="test11" ng-init="test11=0">
             <option value="MULTIMETER" ng-value="60">MULTI</option>
           </select>` I want to get ( $test = $_POST['test1'] )  the value of $test = 'MULTIMETER' , but now the value show '60'.

Comment: please check case 4 and let me know if got your answer :)

Comment: There are 3 drop down menus , there ng-value = 60, ng-value = 70 ,ng-value = 80 . When I select these from drop down menus current web page should show total of selected items, `<p>Test 1 :   <select name="test1" ng-model="test11" ng-init="test11=0">
                                <option value="MULTIMETER" ng-value="60"></option>
                                <option  value="PLIYER" ng-init=70 >PLIYER</option>
                                <option value="SIDECUTTER" ng-value="80">SGPT</option>`another drop down same as  above

Comment: but I want to add goods(MULTIMETER,PLIYER,SIDECUTTER) to the database

Comment: Problem is OK . I make a function to filter data . Thank you Nitya Kumar...